# Linking an old file to the current file using macro. The old file was created by a colleague who left. Opening old file shows an error cant find proj

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that links an old file to the new file. it moves sheets from the old file to the new file, renames and deltes etc.
This old file was created by a colleague who doesnt work anymore at our place.

Im automatically taken to the code of the old file where it says cant find project or library.

The sheet is Spell Number, idk if they put any add ins or not.

```
Main Function www.MSOfficeGeek.com
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber, Optional MyCurrency As String = "")
    Dim Dollars, cents, Temp
    Dim DecimalPlace, Count
    ReDim Place(9) As String <- error here
```

I have tried  tools->references removed missing projects, then it seemed to work.
Over here , it was Adobe Reader File Preview Type Library
But i cannot do this for every file while linking. Please help.